# batch how to add schedule backup to batch files

Tags: batch-file

I have a .bat file that use xcopy to pickup users pst file from document and setting then copy it to a shared drive. users always for get to double click to run it. How can I add time and date for the .bat file to run on its own. Windows build schedule doesn't work at time. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Batch files can't run on their own. Something has to launch the batch file.

You can use Windows Scheduler to schedule the running of the batch file, and then test for the time when the batch file is run in the batch file itself. If it's not the right time, the batch file can just exit; if it is the right time, the batch file can do the backup.

Scheduled tasks *can* run at a specified time; I have one that runs every weekday (Monday through Friday) at 8:45 AM that runs a process to retrieve files via FTP.

If you need more information about using Windows Scheduled Tasks, you should ask a question about it at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com); that subject is not programming-related and would be off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you mean by `Windows build schedule doesn't work at time` and you don't say when you want this backup to run - hourly? Weekly? Once a day?

What you could do is investigate the use of the `AT` command - that may suit you. Perhaps install a batch to run `AT` in your startup directory.

Or perhaps it would be better to start a hidden batch from the startup directory and use the `TIMEOUT` or `CHOICE` command to make it loop periodically.

You would need to explain your requirement in more detail.